# Django 404: Page not found (404) - URLConf not matching

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django, and my first major project of sorts is to go through an existing Django Web App to update it, streamline it and optimize it in any way that I can. I'm having some difficulty in getting it to run on my machine, however.

When navigating to the local development server at localhost:8000/ I get the following error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in core.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^home/$ [name='portal']
    ^agentexoplanet/admin/
    ^agentexoplanet/agentex/ [name='agentex_redirect']
    ^agentexoplanet/admin/agentex/event/(?P<planetid>\d+)/calibrators/(?P<calid>\d+)/$ [name='agentex_admin_calib']
    ^agentexoplanet/admin/agentex/event/(?P<planetid>\d+)/calibrators/$ [name='agentex_all_calib']
    ^agentexoplanet/admin/
    ^agentexoplanet/
    ^static/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

This is the core.urls file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles import views
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

from agentex import urls
from agentex.views import home
from agentex.admin import calibrator_check, allcalibrators_check
#from admin.site import urls

#from showmestars.views import newimage, latestimages

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    #(r'^api/', include('odin.api.urls')),
    url(r'^home/$', home, name='portal'),
    url(r'^agentexoplanet/admin/', include(admin.site.urls), name='agentexo_admin'),
    url(r'^agentexoplanet/agentex/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/agentexoplanet/'), name='agentex_redirect'),
    url(r'^agentexoplanet/admin/agentex/event/(?P<planetid>\d+)/calibrators/(?P<calid>\d+)/$',calibrator_check, name='agentex_admin_calib'),
    url(r'^agentexoplanet/admin/agentex/event/(?P<planetid>\d+)/calibrators/$',allcalibrators_check, name='agentex_all_calib'),
    url(r'^agentexoplanet/admin/', include(admin.site.urls), name=''), # QUERY
    url(r'^agentexoplanet/',include(admin.site.urls), name='agentexo_urls'),
    #url(r'^showmestars/newimage/$', newimage, {'eventid':0}, name='showmestars_newimage'),
    #url(r'^showmestars/(?P<eventid>\w+)/$', latestimages, name='showmestars_latestimage'),
    #url(r'^showmestars/$', latestimages, {'eventid':0}, name='showmestars_latestimage_event'),
    #url(r'^login/$',login, name='site_login'),
    #url(r'^logout/$',logout, name='site_logout'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', views.serve),
    ]
```

And my project (agentex) urls file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout
from .views import *
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',index, name='index'),
    url(r'^account/login/$', login, {'template_name' :'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^account/logout/$', logout,{'template_name' :'logout.html'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^account/register/$', register, name='register'),
    url(r'^account/$', editaccount, name='editaccount'),
    url(r'^profile/$',profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^planets/$',target, name='target'),
    url(r'^fitsanalyse',fitsanalyse, name='fitsanalyse'),
    url(r'^test',tester, name='tester'),
    url(r'^briefing/read/$',read_manual_check, name='read_manual_check'),
    url(r'^briefing/$',briefing, name='briefing'),
    url(r'^comment/$',addcomment, name='addcomment'),
    url(r'^(?P<code>\w+)/view/$',addvalue, name='addvalue'),
    url(r'^(?P<code>\w+)/graph/update/$',updatedataset, name='updatedataset'),
    url(r'^(?P<code>\w+)/lightcurve/advanced/$',graphview, {'mode' : 'advanced','calid':None}, name='advanced-graph'),
    url(r'^(?P<code>\w+)/lightcurve/me/$',graphview, {'mode' : 'simple','calid':None}, name='my-graph'),
    url(r'^(?P<code>\w+)/lightcurve/calibrator/update/$',classifyupdate, name='classifyupdate'),
    url(r'^(?P<code>\w+)/lightcurve/calibrator/$',graphview, {'mode' : 'ave','calid':None}, name='average-graph'),
    url(r'^(?P<code>\w+)/lightcurve/calibrator/(?P<calid>\w+)/$',graphview, {'mode' : 'ave'}, name='calibrator-graph'),
    url(r'^(?P<code>\w+)/lightcurve/$',graphsuper,name='super-graph'),
    url(r'^(?P<code>\w+)/$',infoview, name='infoview'),
    url(r'^(?P<code>\w+)/data.(?P<format>\w+)',measurementsummary, name='measurementsummary'),
]
```

I'm not entirely sure of the error here. My core.urls file links to index.html, but I imagine it isn't linking correctly. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks in advance (and apologies for not posting an image - StackOverflow wouldn't let me).

Comment: I don't see any rule for `/` on the root level there.

Comment: Seems like your project is somehow configured to have core.urls as the top-level file, rather than agentex.urls. What is the value of your ROOT_URLCONF setting? Also, core.urls is including the admin site urls three times for some reason.